# regex for swap info in SunOs

Tags: regex, linux, sunos

swap command : `/usr/sbin/swap  -s`

I even tried something like `awk '/total/ {print $2}' /usr/sbin/swap -s` but gives me error

swap output :

```
total: 12417784k bytes allocated + 2705800k reserved = 15123584k used, 45459976k available
```

I need to get `used` an `available` values i.e., `15123584k` and `45459976k` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pipe to pass the output of `swap` to `awk`

```
/usr/sbin/swap -s | awk '/total/ {print $2}'
```

To get the value of `15123584k` and `45459976k`, we print out column 9 and column 11 using

```
/usr/sbin/swap -s | awk '/total/ {print $9" "$11}'
```

Comment: Chin: how to print both `15123584k` and `45459976k`?